# Building via MSBuild fails when run as System User

Tags: c++, msbuild, bamboo

We are using Visual Studio 2012 to build our C++ application 
If I run from the commandline in my source folder:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=Win32 Myproject2012.sln
```

it works fine. If it's run via the Buildscript of my buildserver (Atlassian bamboo) I get a lot of errors. The first two lines..

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(347,5): error MSB4018: The "CL" task failed unexpectedly. [C:\data\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\XXX-IMB-JOB1\XXX\common\common.vcxproj] 
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(347,5): error MSB4018: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.FileTracker' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070003) [C:\data\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\XXX-IMB-JOB1\XXX\common\common.vcxproj]
```

What can be the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: could be the path is too long. There are also a couple of things that don't work properly under the system account, like accessing shared network locations etc.

Comment: I tested it too
Created a batch file and run it as SystemUser... this works fines ..

Answer (score 1):

You can run the build outside of Bamboo as system if you use Sysinternals psexec.

```
psexec -i -s cmd.exe
```

Then try `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=Win32 Myproject2012.sln`

Then create a shell that have elevated permissions and retry.
Should help see if its a permissions thing or a path thing. Ive tried building C++ as system and it seems PK.
Or it could be this:
[MSBUILD MSB4018 error](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/959162)

Comment: Thanks for the tipp!
I created a batch file and run it via taskplaner

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem
The System Account has a default temp directory which msbuild doesn't like
I changed it to "c:\temp"  no it works!

If someone else has the problem, you can change it in the registry

```
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Environment
```